# Есть ли разница в употреблении "содействие в чем-либо" и "содействие чему-либо"?

Tags: управление

В словарях встречаются оба варианта: "содействие в чем-либо" и "содействие чему-либо", при этом у меня складывается впечатление, что форма с предлогом употребляется, когда идут два дополнения подряд. Содействие кому-либо в чем-либо или содействие чему-либо.
Буду признательна за разъяснения.
Спасибо.
С уважением,
Екатерина.

Answer (score 1):

Вы все правильно понимаете. Если одновременно с выражением о "содействии в чем-либо" указание на субъекта ("кого-либо"), которому содействуют (т. е. помогают своим действием), **не** содержится *явно*, то оно подразумевается

> Оказываем **содействие** [опущено очевидное "клиентам, которые к нам
> обращаются" (*кому* содействие)] **в** получении виз в страны Шенгена.

или уже содержится в предшествующем контексте:

> С удовольствием помогу *тебе* на участке. Могу оказать содействие
> (посодействовать) в прополке клубники.

В случае же содействия **чему-либо** речь идет не о *помощи* кому-либо, а о действии, усиливающем другое названное действие (процесс) или его последствия. Субъект этого (основного) действия не всегда известен, а если он имеется, то упоминается иначе (содействие какому-либо действию *со стороны кого-либо* или совершаемому *кем-либо*).

> Неожиданные показания свидетеля защиты стали *содействием* новым
> *обвинениям* подзащитного со стороны прокурора [=~прокурором].